# Why is this JS Function doing a forloop without any reason?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, jsx

So this issue drive me crazy a little bit because I just couldn't figure this out, I am running a very simple function nested in another one, when I do console.log everthing working as expected but when I implement the firebase stuff it start repeating the same code over and over and over again, then my computer freeze.

```
upvote = index => {
    fire
        .database()
        .ref(`/feed/${this.state.keys[index]}`)
        .on('value', snapshot => {
            var obj = snapshot.val().score;
            this.setState({ score: obj }, () => {
                console.log(typeof this.state.score);
                console.log(this.state.score + 1);
                fire
                    .database()
                    .ref(`/feed/${this.state.keys[index]}`)
                    .update({
                        score: this.state.score + 1,
                    });
            });
        });
};
```

The goal here is to upvote on posts just like reddit, what I'm doing is probably not correct but here's the logic behind it:

```
    <Button
    onClick={() => this.upvote(index)}
    >
```

I do have this array this.state.list where all the posts are stored, I take the `index` of the post I want to upvote then pass it to the function.

Inside the function I run a quick fetch of the actual score, when the db respond I check type of that variable, as expected it's `number`.

Doing `console.log(this.state.score + 1);` returns the exact value but when trying to push that, I end up with some huge numbers like 2983 when restarting the app..

Please someone assist

Comment: Is it possible that your database is returning a list of records, and `on` callback is being called for each record.  Have you checked database response ?

Comment: `on value` callback is set up until you will unlisten it. You update the value and receive updated value. That's recursion. Shouldn't it be `.once('value', ...)`?

Comment: .on is what is causing your issue. On is a listener so it is repeatedly calling setState and overloading your computer. Honestly if I were you I would scrap this piece of code and try rewriting a different solution.. seems like a problematic way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by just decomposing the main function. Thanks to everyone for participating but as I explained in my post there was no recursion when doing only `console.log()` so it's just nesting one db query inside another one that cause the function to run indefinitely because of the updates.

```
upvote = index => {
    fire
        .database()
        .ref(`/feed/${this.state.keys[index]}`)
        .once('value', snapshot => {
            var obj = snapshot.val().score;
            this.setState({ score: obj }, () => this.up(index));
        });
};

up = index => {
    console.log(this.state.score);
    fire
        .database()
        .ref(`/feed/${this.state.keys[index]}`)
        .update({
            score: this.state.score + 1,
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`.on('value'` is returning all the values and changes in the in the DB. 
In `update`, you're doing a change therefor `on` receives it, and then it is again calling update, and you have here a recursion.